# How would you create something similar to this flower?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I am guessing that out of Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop, and InDesign, you would use Photoshop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out the masking that Confused suggested I do to " isolate the effects to portions of the imagery."

Comment: /Users/elizabeth/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-09-21 at 11.21.01 AM.png   This is what I have so far, but the desaturation part I am having trouble with making it to work. The other flower part rectangle is what I am trying to desaturate.

Comment: It didn't work. I was trying to show what I had done so far. How can I attach another image?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please know this site is not a tutorial board.  To learn more about what the site is about please take the [tour] and read [ask].  After reading those please make an [edit] to include further detail in your question and we can re-open it to assist you.

Comment: My question has already been answered thank you very much.

Comment: @ElizabethHart if you haven't seen I just posted in chat showing a correct way. While Confused showed a solution, it was a very poor one which probably explains why he thinks the interface is so bad. Here's all the layers you should need: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qVGZV.jpg -- if you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you Ryan, yes I just saw your post in chat. If I have questions, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is best done in Photoshop. This is known as effects processing of imagery in that:

(on the left) a desaturation effect has been applied.

and

(on the right) an exaggerated halftone effect.

---

Masking is required to isolate the effects to portions of the imagery, something that Photoshop is good at, even if the UX is clunky, retarded and antiquated.

---

Additional commentary on some of the steps to achieve the desired effects upon an image in Photoshop

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45750/discussion-on-answer-by-confused-how-would-you-create-something-similar-to-this).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this layering effect by duplicating layers in Photoshop and applying a [Layer Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) to pick out the parts of the photo you want to apply the monochromatic coloring to or the halftone effect. To do a monochromatic coloring other than black and white you go to Image Adjustments and should be able to alter the saturation of the photo on the left side and "colorize" it to make it monochromatic. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I didn't even know that there was an Autodesk. I was asking about Autocad because I am looking for a job and one of last ones someone told me about Autocad was brought up amongst other things. It got me to wondering if I should see if a trial version is available to use so I can see what it is all about?  I have classmates who would talk about Maya this and Maya that. : )–

Comment: I studied graphic design but I am quite rusty in the Photoshop department. I use it the least. Well that and Dreamweaver. Photoshop seems so counterintuitive and I guess that if you don't use it lose it, your Photoshop skills that is.

Comment: Sorry, @ElizabethHart, I didn't see these replies. AutoCAD can only get you jobs if you're really good at it. It's a specialists field for drawing buildings and their plans, mostly. It has much better 2D drawing facilities than things like Photoshop and Illustrator, which is a good reason to start learning it. But it's really finicky and quite staid and boring to learn. The best 2D vector drawing tools are (un-ironically) 3ds Max and CorelDraw. Ultimately the best freelance jobs are given to displayed talent, and the drone (cube-farm) jobs are about proficiency in known apps, like Photoshop.

Comment: @ElizabethHart Yes, Photoshop is a myriad of user conventions that are counterintuitive. Much like the rules of this "forum". I recommend moving your thinking and life to Quora and/or Adobe forums. They're much friendlier, and realer. The rules here have created a fascist-lite-like bizarro world amongst the "moderators".

Comment: If you want to see the potential that Adobe once had, learn a little After Effects. It shows they were once thinking with their heads on right... and then lost the map. It's much more interesting and fun than Flash, Photoshop, Illustrator and Dreamweaver combined. But also suffers the counter intuitive problems of the rest of their lineup. It is ironic that it's all design software that was never designed, it just grew in an ad hoc manner.

Comment: You seem to have a good sense of balance and weight in imagery, so whack together a portfolio as fast as possible and try to work independently, if you can. Far more challenging, and rewarding.

Comment: @Confused, Thank you so much for replying back about AutoCad. I used to play around with home builder software. I know that it is not in the same ball park as AutoCad, but the curiosity in me wants to give it a try provided I can find a trial version.                                     I have heard of CorelDraw. It looks cool.                                               Thank you for the advice. I have noticed that, kinda cold.

Comment: @Confused How can you tell that I "seem to have a good sense of balance and weight in imagery?"

Comment: @ElizabethHart in the screenshot of your working in Photoshop, your framing is good. That's either a lucky accident or very deliberate.

Comment: @ElizabethHart Judging by the way you lined up the Layers panel in your comp of the screenshot, it's not an accident.

Comment: @Confused I didn't even realize that I had done that. : ) Thank you for the compliment.